# Move HTML based on hash in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do when a user visits the page, the anchor in the url will determine what content is shown at the top. This should be done on the client side, not on the server side.

For example, let's say I have the HTML:

```
<div id='menuitems'>
  <div id='appetizer'>HTML here</div>
  <div id='maincourse'>HTML here</div>
  <div id='dessert'>HTML here</div>
</div>
```

So what I want is when the user visits this page:

`mypage.html#dessert`

Instead of the usual anchor text behavior, I want to use something like jquery to move the dessert text to the top. So the HTML the user see is this:

```
<div id='menuitems'>
  <div id='dessert'>HTML here</div>
  <div id='appetizer'>HTML here</div>
  <div id='maincourse'>HTML here</div>
</div>
```

or: `mypage.html#maincourse`

```
<div id='menuitems'>
  <div id='maincourse'>HTML here</div>
  <div id='appetizer'>HTML here</div>
  <div id='dessert'>HTML here</div>
</div>
```

If there's no anchor or it's unrecognized then just don't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
$(document).ready(){
    $('#menuitems > ' +location.hash).prependTo('#menuitems');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

Comment: That might be better written as `$('#menuitems').children(location.hash).prependTo('#menuitems');`  so you only search the children, not everything underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { 
    $(window.location.hash).prependTo('#menuitems') 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With you don't  want to replace all links attributes. You can do that (with Jquery):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(){
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
    return false;
});
```